# What's better checking for record with active status or taking the status field and then checking

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a bit confusion as to use which method. My requirement is like this:

Suppose there is a table named `user_master`. And it has the follwing fields:
`user_id user_name pwd status`.
The status field is 'A' when Active and 'I' when inactive

What I want is to check if a user is active on the basis of the userid. So whats better

A) `SELECT <any_one_field> FROM user_master WHERE user_id = 'some_user_id' AND status = 'A';`

and then check for more than 0 rows

OR

B) `SELECT status FROM user_master WHERE user_id = 'some_user_id';`
and then compare the status field value for 'A' Active or 'I' Inactive.

Whats better according to below,
In A, there is only SQL and in B, there is SQL + the Programming language stuff.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point A, it already filtered base on userid and status criteria, in sql execution time it more faster but when you don't know the status from user you will choose option B, it will return userid and status that you want to process in next business flow.

Answer (score 1):

It gives you records those who are active

```
SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE status ='A';
```

This query returns if your user_id is active

```
SELECT <any_one_field> FROM user_master WHERE user_id = 'some_user_id' AND status = 'A';
```

This query returns the particluar user_id status

```
SELECT status FROM user_master WHERE user_id = 'some_user_id';
```

Comment: I know which query will give what. My question was whats better. My mistake I did not mention the perspective from which the better one should be picked. I have edited my question.

Comment: @tarun_tenniso B will be preferable